# Django3.1 error when I try to save post with tags

Tags: django

I have a view inside posts app where I try to save a post with tags. Whenever I add a new tag to the post, I get this error:
[value error at create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7HgB.png)

My view is this one:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'posts/create.html'
    form_class = PostCreationForm
    model = Post

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('posts:detail', kwargs={"slug": self.object.slug})

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()  # this is where the error occurs
    
        tags = self.request.POST.get("tag").split(",")
    
        for tag in tags:
            current_tag = Tag.objects.filter(slug=slugify(tag))
            if current_tag.count() < 1:
                create_tag = Tag.objects.create(title=tag)
                form.instance.tag.add(create_tag)
            else:
                existed_tag = Tag.objects.get(slug=slugify(tag))
                form.instance.tag.add(existed_tag)

        return super(PostCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

The form I'm using is as follow:

```
class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_method = "post"
        self.helper.field_class = 'form-group'
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('title', css_class="form-control", placeholder='Post title'),
            Field('content', css_class="form-control", placeholder='Post content'),
            Field('category', css_class="form-control"),
            Field('image', css_class="form-control"),
            Field('tag', css_class="form-control", placeholder='tag1, tag2')
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Create New Post', css_class='btn btn-underline-primary'))

    tag = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'image', 'tag']
```

This is the Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField()
    # content = models.TextField()
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='uploads/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="slug", editable=False)  
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1, related_name='posts')  
    tag = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name='posts', blank=True)
    slider_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    hit = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def post_tag(self):
        return ', '.join(str(tag) for tag in self.tag.all())

    def comment_count(self):
        return self.comments.all().count()
```

How can I fix this error: "Field 'id' expected a number but got 't'." (where 't' is the first letter from my first tag: 'test'. If I use another tag, then the error display the first letter of that word).

Comment: Maybe remove the field `tag` from `fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'image', 'tag']`?

Comment: @hedgie Thank you so much. It does work. Could you tell me why it doesn't work when I add the "tag" element to fields list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the field `tag` from `fields = ['title', 'content', 'category', 'image', 'tag']`

The reason this works is that by *including* it, Django automatically creates a [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield) named `tag`.

However, since you are manually handling extracting and saving the tags (using `tags = self.request.POST.get("tag").split(",")`), excluding it from `Meta.fields` guarantees that Django does not *also* try to handle this field.

As such, another solution would be to let Django handle the `tag` form field by completely removing your custom `save()` method.